# Objective-C: Expected identifier or '(' and 3 unknown errors during compilation

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

I face 3 unknown errors during compile suddenly in AppDelegate.h file of a project which was going alright for a month.
which are!

> Parse Issue - Expected identifier or '('
>
> Parse Issue - Expected ')'
>
> Semantic Issue - Unknown type name 'ViewController'; did you mean 'UIViewController'?

I checked my code line by line there is no syntax error or Semantic issue (i have ViewController.h , ViewController.m and ViewController.xib in my project). These are just unknown errors for which xcode show error just in AppDelegate.h file

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;
@class SignInViewController; 

@class StagesViewController;
@class ResultViewController;
@class myFacebook;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
    myFacebook *myFB;
    NSString *appVer;

    
}

+ (NSString*)Username;
+ (void)setUsername:(NSString*)newUser;
+ (NSString*)UserID;
+ (void)setUserID:(NSString*)newId;

@property (nonatomic, retain) myFacebook *myFB;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *theNavigationController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SignInViewController *signInViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) StagesViewController *stagesViewController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ResultViewController *resultViewController;

@end
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated, because I'm searching for these errors since last week but unable to solve it.

Comment: @bitmapdata.com i have added AppDelegate.h file

Comment: Is your ViewController.m file included in your target to get compiled?

Comment: @ctrahey yes ViewController.h is there.. you know when i write this -->  "@class SignInViewController"; 
at the top of this line -->   "@class ViewController";
the compiler then says --> Unknown type name 'SignInViewController' instead of --> Semantic Issue - Unknown type name 'ViewController'; did you mean 'UIViewController'?

Comment: I'm asking about ViewController**.m**, the implementation file, and whether it is marked as included for your target.

Comment: Change the filename to somethingViewController and not plain ViewController. That's a good coding practice. I think your project is missing this file which is why you get this error. @class ViewController forward declaration will avoid the warning but you still need to have that file in your target

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is not in the `AppDelegate.h` that you posted.  That file compiles just fine.

You need to figure out which `.m` file Xcode is trying to compile when it issues the errors.  Go to the Log Navigator (View > Navigators > Show Log Navigator).  Choose your latest build.  It should have a red circle next to it because of the errors.  Click on it to show the log for that build.

You should find a line in the list like “Compile AppDelegate.m” or “Compile ViewController.m” that lists the errors under it.  That's the file that Xcode is trying to compile.

Now go to that file.  Look at the top of the file, where your `#import` statements are.  Check for stray characters that you might have accidentally entered.

If you don't find any stray characters there, go through each imported file.  Look at the end of the file for stray characters, or a missing `@end` statement, or a missing semicolon, or a missing brace, or a missing parenthesis.  Any of these problems will cause compiler errors that show up in the next imported file, or in the `.m` file.

If you're using a revision control system (like git or svn), use it to diff your files.  Look for changes that don't make sense, at the top or end of your `.h` files or the top of your `.m` files.  If you've checked in files while the build was broken, you'll need to diff against an older, working revision.

If you're not using a revision control system, now you know why you need to start using one ASAP.

Comment: you are todays HERO, I cant belive this realy solve my problem.. The problem was in main.c file (there was wrong type parnthesis )

Comment: Thanks a lot, Save my day :)

Answer (score 3):

See Rob Mayoff's answer above for the real problem: errant characters in a .m or .h file.

Just one thing to add to his reply: if you're not using version control, open up your favorite file browser, navigate to your source file tree, and sort the files by date. Start looking in the files you changed most recently.

Comment: looks like comment than answer.

Comment: Agreed, but for some reason, I have no option to comment on Rob's post, only edit it. I wasn't comfortable doing that, so I made a new answer, instead.